# Reading data from a file into a linked list, and searching for elements in the linked list

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list

I am trying to write code and am taking in data from a file and storing it into a struct and creating a linked list.  I don't see any immediate problems with my code but I made a function to check if a zipcode exists within any of the structs in the linked list and it doesn't seem to be working.  Here's what the data from the file looks like:

id,price,bedrooms,bathrooms,sqft,yr_built,zipcode

1370804430,543115,2,1,1380,1947,98199

3744000040,518380,4,2.5,2810,2014,98038

3313600266,190000,3,1,1180,1966,98002

*EDIT* I implemented new code for reading the file into a linked list but my function for finding the zipcode isn't working.  When I enter a zipcode I know exists in the file, nothing gets printed.

```
typedef struct housetype house;
struct housetype{
int id;
int price;
int bedrooms;
double bathrooms;
int sqft;
int year;
int zipcode;
house *next; };


int findzipcode(house* head, int zip){
    house* current = head;
    while(current != NULL){
        if(current->zipcode == zip){
            cout << "Zipcode exists" << endl;
            return 1;
            break;}
            current = current->next;
    }
return 0;}



int main(){
house *head = NULL;
FILE *houseinfo = NULL;
houseinfo = fopen("house-info-v4.txt", "r");

if (houseinfo == NULL) {
    cout << "Error reading file" << endl;
}
else {
    int res;         
    house *last = head;    
    house h;               
    do {
        res = fscanf(houseinfo, "%d,%d,%d,%lf,%d,%d,%d",
                  &h.id, &h.price, &h.bedrooms, &h.bathrooms,
                  &h.sqft, &h.year, &h.zipcode);
        if (res > 0) {      // <== fscanf successful (if file fits!)
            house *n = (house*)malloc(sizeof(house)); 
            memcpy(n, &h, sizeof(house)); 
            n -> next = NULL;
            if (last) last->next = n; 
            if ( ! head) head = n;    
            last = n;               
        }
    } while (res > 0);
}
int zip;
cout << "Enter a zipcode" << endl;
cin >> zip;
findzipcode(head, zip);}
```

Comment: When I use I zipcode I know is in the file, the program doesn't return anything.

Comment: Please pick a language, `C` or `C++`.  Also, please fix the formatting of your code.  Also, `house *n = (house*)malloc(sizeof(house));` If this is C++, why are you using `malloc` instead of `new[]`?

Comment: For ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line  3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent).  4) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  treat a closing brace '}' as a separate statement.

Comment: in C, when calling any of the heap allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc): 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: the 'tag' 'c' says this is written in the C programming language, BUT the actual code contains calls to `cin` and `cout` which are ONLY found in the C++ programming language.  (they are two separate programming languages.

Comment: regarding: `if (res > 0) {      // <== fscanf successful (if file fits!)` the proper return value from `fscanf()` to check for is the number of parameters successfully converted.  In the current scenario, that value is 7.  Any other returned value indicates some error occurred.

Comment: this statement: `cout << "Error reading file" << endl;` mis-informs the user.  The actual problem is the call to `fopen()` failed. suggest using `perror()` to document the failure

Comment: before exiting the program, need to pass all those instances of `house`, created by the calls to `malloc()` to `free()`

Answer (score 0):

The code you present will only load the first item, so if you are searching for later items it won't work.

Notice how the code with the fscanf doesn't have a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you read only one row from data and made one node for linked list. If you want to make linked list then you have to read all rows from file and create node of each row and link it with loop.

For example

```
while (1)
    read_file
    if feof:
        break
    make_node
    add row_info -> node
    link_node
```

Trying to write this code with c++

Answer (score 0):

At least two problems

- `head` remains NULL
- only one house is read from the file

Try something like

```
if (houseinfo == NULL) {
    cout << "Error reading file" << endl;
}
else {
    int res;                // <== fscanf result
    house *last = head;     // <== last house set (head is still null)
    house h;                // <== holds values until fscanf check
    do {
        res = fscanf(houseinfo, "%d,%d,%d,%lf,%d,%d,%d",
                  &h.id, &h.price, &h.bedrooms, &h.bathrooms,
                  &h.sqft, &h.year, &h.zipcode);
        if (res > 0) {      // <== fscanf successful (if file fits!)
            house *n = (house*)malloc(sizeof(house)); // c++ cast malloc
            memcpy(n, &h, sizeof(house)); // <== copy to allocated house
            n -> next = NULL;
            if (last) last->next = n; // last next is our n 
            if ( ! head) head = n;    // set head if necessary
            last = n;                 // last house set is n, now
        }
    } while (res > 0);
}
```

Explanations are in comments. Basically

- loop on *fscanf* until no more lines in file
- read values in local variable `h`
- if *fscanf* successful, allocate and set `n`
- if we have a last, set its *next* to our new `n`
- if `head` not set yet, set it
- finally, `last` points to `n` to be used at next iteration

Comment: I implemented your code but my function to check if a zipcode exists in a list still doesn't return anything

Answer (score 0):

First of all select a language. Either C or C++.

There is a problem in your code. The thing is, you have memory leak here and that in one way is the reason for the problem.

Well to say it in detail, you allocate memory and get input and store it in that memory and then you forget about it. You don't forget but yes there is no way you can access it. This is the memory leak. And then you pass a `NULL` valued pointer to the search function and it returns nothing.

This change will solve the problem,

```
        house *n = malloc(sizeof(house));
        head = n; //<----- We are not losing the allocated memory
        fscanf(houseinfo, "%d.....
        ..
```

Also there is one redundant thing in your code (this is not causing the problem but yes you should know this).

```
        cout << "Zipcode exists" << endl;
        return 1;
        break; //<--- this is redundant
       }
```

Once a `return` statement is executed that `break` will never be executed. Just put the `return` statement. No use putting the `break` here.

Another point you didn't free the allocated memory.(Ah! to free you need to keep track of it - which you didn't do here). After you are done working with it you should free it.

```
       findzipcode(head, zip);
       free(head);
```

Also check the return value of `malloc`. In case it returns `NULL` take necessary action.

Answer (score 0):

in the following proposed code:

1. error conditions are checked and acted upon
2. most of the comments to the question are incorporated

And now, the proposed code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <errno.h>


struct housetype
{
    int id;
    int price;
    int bedrooms;
    double bathrooms;
    int sqft;
    int year;
    int zipcode;
    struct housetype *next;
};
typedef struct housetype house;


void findzipcode(house* head, int zip)
{
    house* current = head;

    while( current )
    {
        if(current->zipcode == zip)
        {
            cout << "Zipcode exists" << endl;
            return;
        }

        current = current->next;
    }
}



int main( void )
{
    house *head = NULL;

    FILE *houseinfo = fopen("house-info-v4.txt", "r");
    if ( !houseinfo )
    {
        cerr << "fopen failed due to" << strerror( errno )  << endl;
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    int res;
    house *last = NULL;
    house h;


    while( 7 == (res = fscanf(houseinfo, "%d,%d,%d,%lf,%d,%d,%d",
                  &h.id, &h.price, &h.bedrooms, &h.bathrooms,
                  &h.sqft, &h.year, &h.zipcode) ) )

        house *n = new house;
        if( !n )
        {
            cerr << "malloc failed due to: " << strerror( errno ) << endl;
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, malloc successful

        memcpy(n, &h, sizeof(house));
        n -> next = NULL;

        if (last)
            last->next = n;

        else if ( ! head)
            head = n;

        last = n;
    }

    int zip;
    cout << "Enter a zipcode" << endl;
    cin >> zip;
    findzipcode(head, zip);

    while( head )
    {
        house *nextHouse = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = nextHouse;
    }
}
```

Of course, if you really want to use C++, then suggest using a `vector` rather than a linked list